# jQuery - I want to pull html5 data-attribute values from a particular element class into an onclick attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, custom-data-attribute

I am assigning a css class `.ga-track` to specify elements that I want to track while also assigning data-attributes `data-category=""`, `data-action=""`, `data-label=""`, `data-value=""`, etc to specific elements as well.

Example :

`$('a, button, form, input').addClass('ga-track');`

`$('form#formid').attr({
      'data-category':'Form Submission',
      'data-action':'Click',
      'data-label':'Specific FormID Label'
    });`

The data attributes and the classes get added correctly.

Now I am trying to imbed an inline Google Analytics onClick event by targeting all elements with the class `.ga-track` by doing `.attr('onclick', '_gaq.push('_trackEvent', ...')` as you can see in the snippet below.

```
$(".ga-track").attr("onclick", _gaq.push('_trackEvent', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction')););
```

I am unsure about the ability to do data-attribute calls in a .attr() function.

I also tried doing `.attr('onclick', myFunction())` and then binding the `myFunction()` to the _ga.push calls in jQuery but it looks like I'm being forced to append an onclick event with the onclick event set inline with the element I'm attempting to target.

**EDIT**

Here's my final working code:

```
$('.ga-track').on('click', function(){
    ga('send', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction'));
});
```

the .on method was definitely better than the .attr method for adding an onclick="" attribute.

I also was using the wrong GA method with analytics.js, previous using the _gaq.push function instead of ga('send' ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `onclick` attribute with jquery, instead use the `.click()` function or `.on('click',..)` and a callback function:

```
$('.ga-track').on('click', function(){
   _gaq.push('_trackEvent', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction'));
})
```

Whats also problematic:

- you used '.addClass('ga-track');' to declare the class name, but `$('.gaTrack')` to search for it (which will not be found...).
- you use `$(this)` to refer to `$('.ga-track')`, but `this` may be something else. Read:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I added the edits to the ga-track. Believe it or not it was that amateur error that was causing most of my issues.

Comment: I also repaired the `onclick` by instead using the `.click()` function and tagged each data-attribute using the `.data` solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(".gaTrack").on("click",function(){
    _gaq.push('_trackEvent', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction'));
});
```

or,

```
$(".gaTrack").click(function(){
    _gaq.push('_trackEvent', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$(".gaTrack").click(function(){
   _gaq.push('_trackEvent', $(this).data('category'), $(this).data('action'), $(this).data('label'), $(this).data('value'), $(this).data('interaction'));
});
```